# How to select full row in a cell horizontally,if tableview is larger than screen

Tags: iphone

My question is somewhat tricky.

I am developing an application in which i am showing some fields in table view.

Unfortunately my fields are going beyond the screen limit that is more than the size of the

screen.What is happening is when i am selecting a cell in the table ,the cell is getting

selected only up to the screen size after that i am able to see the cell selected.

I want my cell to be fully selected.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KocMv.jpg) of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cell` is selected fully, it is the default feature of `Cell` of `tableview`, but you will not able to see your entire selection because your `tableview` size is larger then screen.

Reduce your tableview size exactly same as width of screen then you will able to see entire selection of Cell.

*I hope it helps.*

Comment: Sir..I can't do anything..I want it fully selected...Is there any way?

Comment: can you upload screenshot ? what you want exactly.

Comment: I am new,Please tell me how to upload image

Comment: Upload your images here, `http://imgur.com/` after uploading give me url of uploaded image.

Comment: I have uploaded image in the question

Comment: column1 value `189796` and column2 value `S.E` what are they ? are they two different tableview ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12599/discussion-between-krunal-and-nitish)